# randomize the component values ​of the matrix in PYTHON

Tags: python, matrix, random, components

how to randomize the component values ​​of the matrix in PYTHON

```
I have a matrix (3,3) like this:[[1, 0, 1]
                                 [0, 1, 0]
                                 [1, 1, 0]]
```

How can I random the value of position(2,2) with the range around its current value( for example the value of (2,2)=1 I want it to be random in ranges 0 and 2?

Answer (score 0):

Use the random library to generate a random number between -1 and 1 to add to each number.

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[1.,0,1],
    [0,1,0],
    [1,1,0]])

offset = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 9).reshape(3,3)

print(matrix + offset)
```

Output

```
[[ 0.02289379  0.75034185  1.37015416]
 [ 0.37926424  1.22760644 -0.33893542]
 [ 1.6429681   0.84606654 -0.03456256]]
```

---

Or only for the center position:

```
matrix[1,1] += np.random.uniform(-1, 1)

print(matrix)
```

Output

```
[[1.         0.         1.        ]
 [0.         0.42999722 0.        ]
 [1.         1.         0.        ]]
```

Comment: From the question, it seems that the OP may want to change the value of `matrix[2,2]` in particular so I'd include a variation of your answer that does that? It's unclear though.